# игра Скачки через ООП

Tags: java, ооп

Архитектура:

- вызов главного игрового метода `doGame`.
- внутри метода задание изначальных характеристик.
- основной игровой цикл - метод `isWinner`.

Здесь есть ошибка с недостижимостью оператора `break`. Объясните - почему ? Ну и вообще расскажите, что я делаю не так. Чего не хватает?

```
//первый класс данного `package`

import java.util.Scanner;

public class racesGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        racesGame game = new racesGame();           //  1*
        game.doGame();

    }

    public void doGame() {
        System.out.println("Введите кол-во лошадок: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Racers[] horses = new Racers[scanner.nextInt()];
        System.out.println("Выберите номер скакуна на которого ставите: ");
        int chosenOne = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите длину забега: ");
        int raceDistance = scanner.nextInt();
        for (Racers horse : horses) {
            horse.setHorses();
        }               //2*
        for (int i = 0; i < horses.length; i++) {
            horses[i].name = i;

        }
        while (isWinner(horses, raceDistance, chosenOne))
            for (Racers horse : horses) {
                horse.addDist();
            }
    }

    public boolean isWinner(Racers[] horses, int raceDistance, int chosenOne) {
        for (int i = 0; i < horses.length; i++) {
            if (horses[i].getHorseDistance() >= raceDistance) {
                for (int j = 0; j < horses.length; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < horses.length; k++) {
                        if (horses[j].getHorseDistance() > horses[k].getHorseDistance()) {
                            Racers temp = horses[j];
                            horses[j] = horses[k];
                            horses[k] = temp;

                        }
                    }
                }
                if (horses[horses.length].name == chosenOne) {
                    System.out.println("Ваша ставка сыграла");
                }
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


//второй класс данного package

public class Racers {
    int minSpeed;
    int maxSpeed;
    int horseDistance;
    int name;

    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(int name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Racers(int minSpeed, int maxSpeed, int horseDistance) {
        this.minSpeed = minSpeed;
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
        this.horseDistance = horseDistance;
    }


    public int getMinSpeed() {
        return minSpeed;
    }

    public void setMinSpeed() {
        this.minSpeed = (int) (10 + (Math.random() * 10));
    }

    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }

    public void setMaxSpeed() {
        this.maxSpeed = (int) (20 + (Math.random() * 40));
    }

    public int getHorseDistance() {
        return horseDistance;
    }

    public void setHorseDistance(int horseDistance) {

        this.horseDistance = horseDistance;
    }

    public void setHorses() {
        this.setMinSpeed();
        this.setMaxSpeed();
        this.horseDistance = 0;

    }


    public void addDist() {
        this.horseDistance += (this.getMinSpeed() + this.getMaxSpeed()) / 2;

    }
   
}
```

И вопрос конкретнее: почему недостижим оператор `break` внутри метода `isWinner` и правильно ли поставлено условие внутри цикла?

```
while (isWinner(horses, raceDistance, chosenOne))
```

И почему код крашится на этапе `horse.addDist();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня ваш код крашится там, где и должен, то есть на строчке:

```
for (Racers horse : horses) {
    horse.setHorses(); // <- Здесь
}
```

потому что вы создали массив, заполненного null. После создания массива, его надо инициализировать реальными объектами.

Сделать это можно следующим образом (в вашем случае):

```
Racers[] horses = new Racers[scanner.nextInt()];

for(int i = 0; i < horses.length; i++) {
    horses[i] = new Racers();
}
```

Далее, вместо метода `setHorses()` добавьте конструктор по умолчанию в ваш класс `Races`, с тем же содержимым. Однако, лучше использовать инициализирующий конструктор, который у вас уже есть (добавив аргумент с именем лошади) - так логичнее, чем использовать по-умолчанию (который лучше сделать приватным, или защищенным) который создает сферического коня в вакууме.

Лучше переименовать класс Races в RaceHorse

В вычислении пройденной дистанции не хватает времени `S = V*dt`, хотя если вы имели в виду единицу времени, то все ок.

Начальное значение дистанции лошади надо инициализировать нулем.

Answer (score 1):

до `break`а не доходит потому что после `return` функция завершается